# A glow around a circular image with CSS on hover

Tags: css

I want there to be a "glow" effect around a circular image I have (it appears as a circle, but it really is a square image with transparent pixels to make it appear as a circle).

Is there an easy and efficient way to do this with CSS?  I have tried box shadow, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do something like this with `box-shadow` and CSS `animation`

```css
img {
  margin: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 4px #747DE8;
  animation: glow 1.5s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes glow{
  to {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 20px #535FED;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/000000/ffffff">
```

Also you could use some [`Filters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) on `img`. [`Support`](http://caniuse.com/#search=filter)

```css
.element {
  margin: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 4px #747DE8;
  animation: glowShadow 1.5s linear infinite alternate;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: glowImage 1.5s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes glowShadow{
  to {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px 15px #535FED;
  }
}

@keyframes glowImage{
  to {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(2);
     filter: brightness(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <img src="http://www.officialpsds.com/images/thumbs/Blue-Planet-psd85316.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you.

```css
.box-shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 5px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px light green;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px light blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-shadow">
  <img src="path to image" />
  <h1> Text In a Glowing Box.</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of the border-radius: property and the :hover pseudo class to get the desired effect.

Basically, set the images border-radius to 50% - this will make your image a perfect circle.  Using the :hover psuedoclass will allow you to set the styling of a mouse:hover event.

HTML:

```
<img src="https://aedesnoyers.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/night11.jpg" class="round-hover" />
```

Your CSS will look something like:

```
.round-hover {
  height: 200px;  /*Resize for Fiddle*/
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.round-hover:hover{

  /* thank you @Morgan Clark */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 5px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px light green;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px light blue;
}
```

Seen here in the fiddle:

[Shadow over image when hovering](https://jsfiddle.net/ey2gmev4/)

--SIDE NOTE-- the first two 0's of the box-shadow: property make it so there's no offset in your box shadow.  This makes it appear to "glow"

**EDIT**
After seeing @NENAD's answer, I may have misinterpreted what was asked of a "glowing" effect.