# Create a circle with 2 stroke

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, amcharts

I use the library [amchart](https://www.amcharts.com/) to create a chart. On this chart, there is some bullet created with the element "circle". It's possible to create a border on this bullet but I would also like to create a halo to it to reach this kind of result :

[image]

But actually I just get something like this :

```css
circle 
{
  r:5;
  cx:0;
  cy:0;
  fill:#36004E;
  stroke:#FFFFFF;
  stroke-width:2;
}

body {
  background: #333;
}

.module {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

svg {
  fill: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="module">
  <svg version="1.1">
    <circle  transform="translate(8,52)" aria-label=" Nov 06, 2017 1.04" class="amcharts-graph-bullet"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I try to use the CSS property :

- :after
- :before
- text shadow

but nothing work until now.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754734/a-glow-around-a-circular-image-with-css-on-hover

Comment: I already try box-shadow but it's look like it don't have any effect on the element circle

Comment: Try reuse your circle with `<use>` and stroke the `<use>` element for the second stroke.

Comment: I can't add anything in the HTML.

Comment: The problem is that you can't use  `r:5; cx:0; cy:0;`in your css You'll have to move at least the r in the SVG

Comment: why I could not? I can change these values in the CSS